# Podman logging filebeat

Tags: filebeat, podman

We're currently deploying zookeeper and kafka instances via podman. Now we're trying to fetch the logging it is generating with a filebeat instance. But we're getting the following error:

Error message:

ERROR instance/beat.go:958 Exiting: error in autodiscover provider settings: error setting up docker autodiscover provider: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

For the life of me i cannot figure out how to fix this, looked at Stackoverflow and Reddit but nothing came up so far. Now i was thinking of a way so that Podman stores the logging externally (which i know Docker does) but even this is something that i cannot seem to find on the internet. My command file is as follows:

```
alias docker=podman

docker run -d \
--name zookeeper \
--env ZOO_SERVER_ID=1 \
--env ZOO_SERVERS=
--env ZOO_ENABLE_PROMETHEUS_METRICS=yes \
--env ZOO_PROMETHEUS_METRICS_PORT_NUMBER=10001 \
--env ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes \
--env ZOO_TLS_CLIENT_ENABLE=true \
--env ZOO_TLS_PORT_NUMBER=3181 \
 \
--env ZOO_TLS_CLIENT_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD="!" \
-p 2181:2181 \
-p 3181:3181 \
-p 10001:10001 \
-p 2888:2888 \
-p 3888:3888 \
bitnami/zookeeper:3.6.2
```

Any idea how i can program this in such a way that it stores the logging outside in a file which i can let the filebeat pick up?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: Regarding the error message: _Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock_. If you want unix:///var/run/docker.sock to be available inside the container, you could run `podman system service` (see [man page](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/master/docs/source/markdown/podman-system-service.1.md)) outside of the container to create the Unix domain socket and then bind-mount it into the container with the `-v` command-line option to `podman run ...`. Passing in the Unix domain socket into the container comes with security problems though.

Comment: there is no daemon when running podman, or am I missing sth?